# Check if associative array contains value, and retrieve key / position in array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, associative

I'm struggling to explain what I want to do here so apologies if I confuse you.. *I'm just as confused myself*

I have an array like so:

```
$foo = array(
    array('value' => 5680, 'text' => 'Red'), 
    array('value' => 7899, 'text' => 'Green'), 
    array('value' => 9968, 'text' => 'Blue'), 
    array('value' => 4038, 'text' => 'Yellow'),
)
```

I want to check if the array contains the value e.g. 7899 and also get the text linked to that value "Green" in the example above.

Comment: What about foreach()? ...

Comment: 7899 is not linked to 'yellow'. And exactly what u have to do?

Comment: @rack_nilesh Apologies for that rack_nilesh.. Addressed that issue.

Comment: @Phantom I thought about that but I'm already nested within 2 other foreach loops and was wondering if there was a better way of doing so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$foo = array(
    array('value' => 5680, 'text' => 'Red'), 
    array('value' => 7899, 'text' => 'Green'), 
    array('value' => 9968, 'text' => 'Blue'), 
    array('value' => 4038, 'text' => 'Yellow'),
);

$found = current(array_filter($foo, function($item) {
    return isset($item['value']) && 7899 == $item['value'];
}));

print_r($found);
```

Which outputs

```
Array
(
    [value] => 7899
    [text] => Green
)
```

The key here is `array_filter`. If the search value `7899` is not static then you could bring it in to the closure with something like `function($item) use($searchValue)`. Note that `array_filter` is returning an array of elements which is why I pass it through `current`

Comment: Side Note: with dynamic search value `$found = current(array_filter($activityArray, function($item) use($jobID) {
     return isset($item['jobid']) && $jobID == $item['jobid'];
 }));

 print_r($found);`

Answer (score 4):

For PHP >= 5.5.0 it is easier with `array_column`:

```
echo array_column($foo, 'text', 'value')[7899];
```

Or to be repeatable without using `array_column` each time:

```
$bar = array_column($foo, 'text', 'value');
echo isset($bar[7899]) ? $bar[7899] : 'NOT FOUND!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess at what you would like here:

```
function findTextByValueInArray($fooArray, $searchValue){
    foreach ($fooArray as $bar )
    {
        if ($bar['value'] == $searchValue) {
            return $bar['text'];
        }
    }
}
```