# Check array value exists in another associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two different arrays (say) `array1` and `array2`. I want to check whether a value in `array2` exists in `array1`.

```
Array1
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [title] => Course1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
         [id] => 8
         [title] => course2
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [title] => course3
    )
)

Array2
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
)
```

I used:

```
foreach ($array2 as $id) {
    $found = current(array_filter($array1, function($item) {
       return isset($item['id']) && ($id == $item['id']);
    }));
    print_r($found);
}
```

When I run this code it give the following error:

```
Undefined variable: id
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760004/check-if-associative-array-contains-value-and-retrieve-key-position-in-array

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you update your question to show us exactly what you tried and what output you expect to get.

Comment: Not clear to understand

Comment: Mention your code you have try to do this logic

Comment: please see my updated ques @Krishan Patel

Comment: @DeepKakkar While that post shows how to solve the problem of finding an item in another array, it bypasses the OP actual problem: failure to pull `$id` from the parent scope into the closure.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that you are trying to use a variable within your anonymous function that is not available to it. Have a read of the [relevant PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (esp. Example #3) to make sure you are clear on what I'm talking about.

In brief, your variable `$id` is declared in the parent scope of your closure (or anonymous function). In order for it to be available within your closure you must make it available via the `use` statement.

If you change the key line of your code to be:

```
$found = current(array_filter($array1, function($item) use ($id) {
```

your program should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple code as per your question :

```
foreach($array2 as $id){

        return in_array($id, array_column($array1, 'id'));

}
```

Make sure this is a useful to you.