# Associative array replace

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

These arrays contains same keys simple like follow topic (`prop` is unique): 
[Check if associative array contains value, and retrieve key / position in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760004/check-if-associative-array-contains-value-and-retrieve-key-position-in-array)

```
<?php
$array = array(
array("prop" => "1", "content" => "text"),
array("prop" => "2", "content" => "text"),
array("prop" => "3", "content" => "text"),
array("prop" => "4", "content" => "text")
);
$found = current(array_filter($array, function($item) {
  return isset($item['prop']) && 3 == $item['prop'];
}));
print_r($found);
```

I got `prop` 3:

```
Array
(
  [prop] => 3
  [content] => text
)
```

So I want to replace value in `$array` with:

```
array("prop" => "3", "content" => "replaced text")
```

Comment: What?  What result do you want?

Comment: array("prop" => "3", "content" => "replaced text") in $array

Comment: Is `prop` always unique?

Comment: yes always is unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `prop` is unique, just extract the arrays using `prop` as the index and then access it that way:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'prop');
$array[3]['content'] = 'replaced text';
```

You might want to use an `isset` to make sure `$array[3]['content']` exists.

Comment: Technically shouldn't the OP access the value as `$array['3']['content']`, since "prop" is a string in the original array? I believe accessing it by an integer could cause issues between array position and array key name.

Comment: @Anthony: PHP creates integer keys from strings containing only integers `var_dump(["1"=>"hello", "a"=>"hello"]);`